# How to use eas secret variable in app.json?

Tags: react-native, expo

```
eas secret:create
✔ Linked to project @ho-jin/loveyou (https://expo.dev/accounts/ho-jin/projects/loveyou)
✔ Secret name: … SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN
✔ Secret value: … "secret value"
✔ ️Created a new secret SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN on project @ho-jin/loveyou.
```

I generated a key.

| Name | Scope | ID | Updated at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN | project | my key id | Jun 24 23:37:54 |

`eas secret:list` And I checked that the key exists.
How to use eas secret variable in app.json?

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "러브유",
    "slug": "loveyou",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "net.nextlevels.loveyou",
      "buildNumber": "3"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "net.nextlevels.loveyou",
      "versionCode": 3
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": ["sentry-expo"],
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "individual-ph",
            "project": "loveyou",
            "authToken": process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN << but error
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried `process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN`.
but an error occurred.

Does expo provide a way to add secret to app.json?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a file called `app.config.js` (or .ts) to your root folder.

This file will modify programatically the app.json file and inject the env. variables you need.

Your file will be like this:

```js
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  return {
    ...config,
    hooks: {
      postPublish: [
        {
          file: 'sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps',
          config: {
            organization: 'individual-ph',
            project: 'loveyou',
            authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  };
};
```

Then, if you're using EAS Build, you have to add the SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN to your project's secrets. The link to add is: https://expo.dev/accounts/ho-jin/projects/loveyou/secrets

The way you wanted to use, was supposed to be working like this with EAS Build inside your app.json:

```js
...
 "authToken": "$(SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN)"
...
```

But I am not sure if this is working.

You can read more about Expo Secrets at:
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/